# CMake: how to install one target into two places with different name?

Tags: cmake

I am developing a cross-platform audio plugin. In MacOSX, it needs to be installed into two places: `~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/` and rename to XXX.component, `~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/` and rename to XXX.vst.

However, the TARGETS mode for INSTALL command cannot do rename, while the FILES mode cannot get target's real file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get target's real file name using properties of that target:

```
get_target_property(MY_LIB_PREFIX <my-lib> PREFIX)
get_target_property(MY_LIB_SUFFIX <my-lib> SUFFIX)
set(MY_LIB_FILENAME "${MY_LIB_PREFIX}<my-lib>${SUFFIX}")
```

and then use `install(FILES ...)` command for install file with new name.

Also, you can change extension of target built using its `SUFFIX` property. This allows you to perform one install using `install(TARGETS ...)` command. Other installation will require `install(FILES ...)` command anyway.

If you have CMake of version 3.0 or higher, [generator-expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)) provide simpler way for get full path of the file::

```
install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:my-lib> ...)
```

Comment: No, you can't get target's real path through that way. When you generate MSVC or XCode projects, Target is not  on ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}. Instead, they are on ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>, where the $<CONFIG> is not defined at CMake run stage, but are generated at project generation stage.

Comment: `install(FILES ...)` allows for filenames to be generator-expressions, so multiconfig projects are not a problem. I have updated my answer for this case.

Comment: Thanks for a lot! But what if the TARGET is a MacOSX bundle which is actually a directory? Use install(PATH...)?

Comment: I am not sure, but probably `install(DIRECTORY $<TARGET_FILE:my-lib>/ DESTINATION <desired-installation-dirname> ...)` should work for MacOSX bundle. Trailing '/' in directory name avoids copiing directory itself into destination.

Comment: How exactly would I "then use install(FILES ...) command for install file with new name"?

Comment: @ThomasFritz: E.g. `install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:my-lib> DESTINATION bin RENAME foo1)`. Parameter `RENAME` is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files).