# How does CMake know which prefixes and suffixes to add to shared libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake, installation, targets

I am trying to use INSTALL in CMake to copy some external binaries to an install directory.  My code goes like:

```
SET(SimTK_SHARED_LIBS 
    SimTKsimbody 
    SimTKmath
    SimTKcommon
    SimTKmolmodel
)

INSTALL(TARGETS ${SimTK_SHARED_LIBS} 
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
)
```

I get this error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:216 (INSTALL):
>      install TARGETS given target "SimTKsimbody" which does not exist in this
>      directory.

this is in spite of putting files called both `libSimTKsimbody.so` and (incorrectly) `SimTKsimbody` in the current directory as well as in the library directory.

Interestingly, this:

```
SET(SHARED_MMB_TARGET MMBlib)
ADD_LIBRARY(${SHARED_MMB_TARGET} SHARED
    ${MMB_LIBRARY_SOURCE_FILES}
    ${MMB_HEADER_FILES})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${SHARED_MMB_TARGET} 
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-DMMB_BUILDING_SHARED_LIBRARY"
    PROJECT_LABEL "MMBlib (dynamic)")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${SHARED_MMB_TARGET}
          ${SimTK_SHARED_LIBS_D}
          ${SimTK_SHARED_LIBS}
          ${OpenMM_SHARED_LIBS_D}
          ${OpenMM_SHARED_LIBS}
          ${SimTK_GENERAL_LIBS})

INSTALL(TARGETS ${SHARED_MMB_TARGET}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
)
```

.. works fine. It installs `libMMBlib.so` in `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib` as it should.  Does this mean that INSTALL will only work for this if I issue ADD_LIBRARY and/or SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES? The SimTK_SHARED_LIBS are compiled separately, I really do not want to compile them here.

I have thought about using INSTALL FILES, and just writing code to process the library names for each operating system. However I am convinced that CMake has the means to do this for me easily and elegantly.

Many thanks

Sam

Comment: `INSTALL(TARGETS)` works only with CMake **targets**, which created using ADD_EXECUTABLE or ADD_LIBRARY. That why you get error in the first case. `INSTALL(FILES)` works, as opposite, with bare files. Preferred way is to use `INSTALL(TARGETS)` whenever possible.  As for constructing library name, you can use target's property. See that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31627913/3440745

Comment: OK, but if I call ADD_LIBRARY, it will try to build this library if it can't find it.  Is that correct? This CMakeLists.txt doesn't have instructions for building that lib. I guess that would be OK, since if the library is not where it should be then the compilation should be aborted anyway. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: .. and thanks for the reformatting!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use INSTALL(FILES) for install external libraries files.

CMake uses [CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX.html) and [CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html) as default prefix and suffix for libraries created with `add_library(... SHARED)`, so you may expect these components from external library:

```
INSTALL(FILES /path/to/library/${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}SimTKsimbody${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    ...)
```

Also you may use [FIND_LIBRARY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) for automatic(and nice) check of your expectations about library suffix and prefix:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(SIMTK_SIMBODY_LIB
    ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}SimTKsimbody${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    PATH /path/to/library)

INSTALL(FILES ${SIMTK_SIMBODY_LIB} ...)
```